# Half transparent screen on top of another full screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a screen like below which will allow user to show few buttons on top of another screen . So basically it will be on top of another screen which can be seen from the half transparent screen of the top level screen. Not sure how to create it and which widget to use. Can someone please guide here. I am trying to do this using flutter to create android as well as ios app.

[image: Image added which i am trying to acheive]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the stack widget here, develop your first screen and another one which you want to put on top. Put both in stack widget so one can come on top of another one.

On the screen which should be on top, make the first half of it transparent (which can be attained in different ways, one of it would be to use a Card with elevation of 0).

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate answer would be do use an an showModalBottomSheet which we expand from the button into the screen and will also color the screen darker. Example code could be following:

```
await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 200);
  },
)
```

With the current answer you would have to write the entire funtionality for it by yourself, which could be quite unnecessary when there is already a widget out there for exactly this case